# Histogram does not show up in f-distribution plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, distribution

I am trying to create f-distributed random numbers with given degree of freedoms d1 and d2, and plot both a histogram with f-distributed random numbers, and plot an idealised f-distribution curve, but when I give small values to df's, the histogram does not show up. I am new at statistics and matplotlib, and I could not figure out how to deal with this problem.
This is my code:

```
def distF(request, distribution_id):
    dist = get_object_or_404(Distribution, pk=distribution_id)
    dfd = dist.var4
    dfn = dist.var2
    x = np.random.f(dfn, dfd, size = dist.var3)
    num_bins = 50

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    print(x)
    # the histogram of the data
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, num_bins, normed=True)
    y = np.linspace(0, 5, 1001)[1:]
    dist = st.f(dfn, dfd, 0)
    #y = np.linspace(st.f.ppf(0.01, dfn, dfd), st.f.ppf(0.99, dfn, dfd), 100)
    ax.plot(y, dist.pdf(y), '--')

    ax.set_xlabel('Smarts')
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
    ax.set_xlim([0, 4])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 3])
    fig.tight_layout()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    plt.close(fig)
    return response
```

This is how the plots look like:

[image: F-distribution plot with small df values]
F-distribution plot with small df values

[image: F-distribution plot with large df values]
F-distribution plot with large df values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the f distribution with a `dfd` of 1 spreads out hugely towards large numbers. So let's say you have values of 2000 or so in your array `x`, but only 50 bins between 0 and 2000. That makes the bin rather large and hence rather low in height. I would think that if you anyway want to limit your view to some low number, it would be better to also limit the histogram to that number.

In the code below the limit would be 5 and the bin width is 0.2.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfn = 10
dfd =1
limit = 5

x = np.random.f(dfn, dfd, size = 100)
bins = np.arange(0, limit, 0.2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, bins, normed=True)
y = np.linspace(0, limit, 1001)[1:]
dist = st.f(dfn, dfd, 0)

ax.plot(y, dist.pdf(y), '--')

ax.set_xlabel('Smarts')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
ax.set_xlim([0, limit])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]